# .contains only works if hardcoded

Tags: java, string, arraylist

This is my first post, so please let me know if something should be different.

I've been trying to create a method that finds the index of a search term in a two dimensional ArrayList. This is the code I came up with:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Searcher {
public static int Search(List<List<String>> csv, String term) throws TermNotFoundException{
    if (csv.get(0).contains(term)) {
        return csv.get(0).indexOf(term);
    }
    else {
        throw new TermNotFoundException("Term not found");
    }
}
```

The problem I have right now is that when I hardcode a search term that occurs in the ArrayList I'm looking at, it works perfectly. The problem occurs when I try to use the term variable as shown above.

the specific ArrayList I'm looking at ( csv.get(0) ) is as follows:

> [datetime_UTC, E1A, E1B, E1C, E2A, E2B, E3A, E3B, E3C, E3D, E4A, G1A, G2A, G2C, Zon]

As such, if I hardcode in "E1A", It'll find it and return 1. This doesn't work if I call the function in the main method and filling in the same thing for the variable term.

Is there something I'm missing?

EDIT: To elaborate, I cannot disclose the full two dimensional array due to privacy reasons. I can, however, show you more info.

Some suggested to not search twice, so I have changed the code as follows:

```
import java.util.List;
public class Searcher {
public static int Search(List<List<String>> csv, String term) throws TermNotFoundException{
    System.out.println(csv.get(0));
    System.out.println(term);
    int result = csv.get(0).indexOf(term);
    if (result != -1){
        return result;
    }
    else {
        throw new TermNotFoundException("Term not found");
    }
}
```

The same problem occurs. Included are some debugging lines, here is the output:

```
[datetime_UTC, E1A, E1B, E1C, E2A, E2B, E3A, E3B, E3C, E3D, E4A, G1A, G2A, G2C, Zon]
E1A
TermNotFoundException: Term not found
at Searcher.Search(Searcher.java:12)
at Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

if it is any help. this is where I'm calling the function from:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.List;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    List<List<String>> csv = CSVReader.Read("standard_profiles.csv");
    try {
        System.out.println(Searcher.Search(csv, "E1A"));
    } catch (TermNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Several notes: You are only checking `csv.get(0)`, what about the other lists? You do `contains` and then `indexOf`, this is doing the work of searching the string twice. And searching in a list is expensive (`O(n)`). Instead, just do `indexOf` without `contains` and if it returns `-1`, it was not found.

Comment: I hardly doubt that this method doesnt work as expected with a dynamic `String`, it looks _correct_. Voting to close as not reproducible. You will have to share more info. For example a [mcve] (emphasis on complete) for both versions (hardcoded string and dynamic string) with the output.

Comment: Your best bet will be to step through the code with a debugger, or to add a `System.out.println(term);` at the start of the method. My guess is that the value you're sending in isn't what you think it is, for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add("000");
    List<List<String>> listList=new ArrayList<>();
    listList.add(list);
    System.out.println(Search(listList, "000"));;
}
```

The above code returns 0, I wasn't able to reproduce your problem. However it won't work if your term isn't on the first list as `.get(0)`means you are only searching the first `List` in your `List<List>`